# Помогите с регуляркой php

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
if( !isset($id) || !preg_match('#^\d{1,10}$#', $id) )
```

он обрабатывает только цифры мне нужно что бы именно в формате

```
ХХХХХ-ХХХХХ-ХХХХХ-ХХХХХ-ХХХХХ
```

где XXXXX там буквы заклавные, цифры, ну а спец символы исключить.

Answer (score 1):

```
$RE=<<< HEREDOC
^
(?:
    [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}
    (?(?=-[a-zA-Z0-9])-)
){5}
\$
HEREDOC;
echo preg_match("/$RE/x", $text);
```

Пример работы здесь:
http://ideone.com/1t81Im
Полностью удовлетворяет заявленным требованиям в вопросе.

Comment: Только кроме заклавных букв тут ещё и передклавные (строчные)

Comment: @alexlz, точно :)  
Для этого надо везде стереть **a-z**, тогда передклавных букв не будет.  
Автор, а междуклавные и подклавные буквы нужны в регулярке ?